# Insert HTML at stage in PHP foreach

Tags: php, foreach

I am running a foreach over an array and am looking to break up my foreach statement into four stages:

```
<?php foreach ($result->data as $post): ?>
    <?php if($photo_count < 2) { ?>
        <!-- Renders images. @Options (thumbnail,low_resoulution, high_resolution) -->
        <a class="col-md-2" rel="group1" href="<?= $post->images->standard_resolution->url ?>"><img src="<?= $post->images->thumbnail->url ?>"></a>

        <?php $photo_count++; ?>
        <?php echo $photo_count; ?>


    <?php } elseif($photo_count = 2) { ?>
        <p>testing</p>
        <?php $photo_count++; ?>
        <?php echo $photo_count; ?>


    <?php } elseif($photo_count > 2) { ?>
        <a class="col-md-2" rel="group1" href="<?= $post->images->standard_resolution->url ?>"><img src="<?= $post->images->thumbnail->url ?>"></a>

        <?php $photo_count++; ?>
        <?php echo $photo_count; ?>

    <?php } else {
        break; 
    } ?>



<?php endforeach ?>
```

Earlier I declared $photo_count to equal 1. Basically what I want to do is:
-When the photo count is less than 2 - do something
-When the photo count is equal to 2 - do something
-When the photo count is great than 2 - do something.

For some reason it is getting stuck when $photo_count is equal to 3 and looping over that.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Just a suggestion, when you have to mix php code with html, I've found it much cleaner and more readable if you use the alternate syntax for php control statements. That way, you don't end up with some random closing curly braces somewhere, and makes debugging much, much easier. Example: `<?php if(cond): ?>...<?php endif; ?>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`=` is assignment and `==` is comparison while `===` is comparison of content as well as datatype.. use them carefully.

Change

```
 elseif($photo_count = 2)
```

to

```
elseif($photo_count == 2)
```

Comment: Ahhhhhh the operator type got me! I also changed the final elseif to: elseif($photo_count > 2 && $photo_count < 5) so it stops after the 5th iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
<?php } elseif($photo_count = 2) { ?>
```

By

```
<?php } elseif($photo_count == 2) { ?>
```

Do not confuse [assignment operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php) and [comparison operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php).

Answer (score 1):

@Danyal Sandeelo's answer is correct, I just want to help you cleanup your code, you dont need too much php tags there, here is a optimized code:

```
<?php 
 foreach ($result->data as $post){
   if($photo_count < 2) {
     echo '<a class="col-md-2" rel="group1" href="'.$post->images->standard_resolution->url.'"><img src="'.$post->images->thumbnail->url.'"></a>';

    $photo_count++;
    echo $photo_count;

   } elseif($photo_count = 2) {
        echo '<p>testing</p>';
        $photo_count++;
        echo $photo_count;
   } 
  elseif($photo_count > 2) {
    echo'<a class="col-md-2" rel="group1" href="'.$post->images->standard_resolution->url.'"><img src="'.$post->images->thumbnail->url.'"></a>';

    $photo_count++;
    echo $photo_count;
   } 
  else {
    break; 
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Luthando.